# error activate feature list template/instance in site definition

Tags: list, visual-studio, list-definition

i've created a SiteDefiniton project and a Sharepoint ListDefinition project. In the SiteDefinition I created a listinstance of my template, but in deployment the activation of the ListInstanceFeture fails with following error:

> "Error 1: Error occurred in deployment step 'Activate Features': Feature 'cb490e2c-b67d-4465-a80f-debffa11aae7' for list template '2010001' is not installed in this farm.  The operation could not be completed."

My ListInstance is just a test, so the Elements.xml is as empty as possible.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Elements xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/">
  <ListInstance 
    Title="Newsletter"
    OnQuickLaunch="TRUE"
    TemplateType="2010001"
    Url="Lists/Newsletter"
    FeatureId="CB490E2C-B67D-4465-A80F-DEBFFA11AAE7"
    Description="Enthält Informationen über alle bisher versandten Newsletter.">
  </ListInstance>
</Elements>
```

I deployed the ListDefinition project separatly and created a ListInstance from the Template... It works, so where are the failure? By now I would be pleased for every little hint.

edit: List Definition Schema.xml (There are some more Fields but they are commented out for testing.)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<List xmlns:ows="Microsoft SharePoint" Title="NewsletterTemplate" FolderCreation="FALSE" Direction="$Resources:Direction;" Url="Lists/NewsletterTemplate" BaseType="0" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/">
  <MetaData>
    <ContentTypes>
      <ContentTypeRef ID="0x01">
        <Folder TargetName="Item" />
      </ContentTypeRef>
      <ContentTypeRef ID="0x0120" />
    </ContentTypes>
    <Fields>
      <Field Name="Title" StaticName="Title" DisplayName="Titel" Type="Text" FromBaseType="TRUE" ID="21A9B1CC-CBEA-4D8A-9AEF-0F1BD7F1BE97" Required="TRUE"/>
    </Fields>
```

Comment: can you show us the list definition? (not the whold schema, but at least the header)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Make sure that the FeatureId attribute in your [ListInstance](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms476062.aspx) matches the ID of the definition's feature.
- Make sure the Type attribute in your [ListTemplate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms462947.aspx) element matches the TemplateType of your [ListInstance](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms476062.aspx) (in your case, 2010001)
- Put both at the same scope. If the definition is at the same scope as its list instance and properly referenced, SharePoint can find it and auto-activate it.

Comment: Logical failure found...
Solution is exactly like you wrote. The FeatureId of the ListInstance was an other than in the ListTemplatesFeature. 

(Thought that the ListInsance is a single feature, which needs an own FeatureId) I changed it in the ListInstance et voilá it works.
Thank you all very much.

Answer (score 0):

I hope you have deployed and activated the list definition feature on the web application or site collection where you are trying to create this site.Please check the same.

Comment: I tried many combinations. My actual settings are:
ListDefinitionsFeature=>Web
ListInstanceFeature=>Site
That were the combination I read in a guide.

Answer (score 0):

I just conquered a similar situation with this error.  The answer was to change the order of the Features in the Visual Studio Package.