# Error occurred in deployment step 'Activate Features': Cannot complete this action

Tags: list, list-definition, feature-dependency

In my SharePoint 2013 solution (created from visual studio), I created a project that contains all the artifacts form my solution: I put in this project custom fields, custom content types as well as custom lists that my solution requires.

Then I created 3 features in this project :

The first feature which is **a site scoped feature** contains **all the custom content types and custom fields** of my solution, its name is *Feature_ContentTypes_Fields*.

The second feature is **a Site Scoped feature** and contains **all list definitions for my custom lists** ***( in which I added "Feature_ContentTypes_Fields" as feature activation dependency)*** , its name is *Feature_ListDefinitions*.

The last feature which is **a web scoped feature** manages the creation of **all list instances of my custom lists** ***( in which I added "Feature_ListDefinitions" as feature activation dependency)*** , its name is *Feature_ListInstances*.

I can successfully build the solution, but it then fails to deploy.

Here is the output of visual studio while deploying the solution:

> ------ Deploy started: Project: Model, Configuration: Debug Any CPU ------ Active Deployment Configuration: Default   Skipping deployment step because a pre-deployment command is not specified.   Recycle IIS
>   Application Pool:   Recycling IIS application pool 'SharePoint -
>   1111'...   Retract Solution:   Deactivating feature
>   'Model_Feature_ListDefinitions' ...   Deactivating feature
>   'Model_Feature_ContentTypes_Fields' ...   Retracting solution
>   'model.wsp'...   Deleting solution 'model.wsp'...   Add Solution:
>   Adding solution 'Model.wsp'...   Deploying solution 'Model.wsp'...
>   Activate Features:   Activating feature 'Feature_ContentTypes_Fields'
>   ...   Activating feature 'Feature_ListDefinitions' ...   Activating
>   feature 'Feature_ListInstances' ... Error occurred in deployment step
>   'Activate Features': Cannot complete this action.

Here you find the manifest of the list definitions feature:

`<Feature xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/" Title="Model ListDefinitions" Id="ab765f54-0a2b-4aa9-b87c-f5066849dc4a" Scope="Site">   <ActivationDependencies>
    <ActivationDependency FeatureId="10412a7b-e033-43a0-a485-1c4f4c83ccca" FeatureTitle="Model ContentTypes_Fields" />   </ActivationDependencies>   <ElementManifests>
    <ElementFile Location="CVs\EditDlg.htm" />
    <ElementManifest Location="CVs\Elements.xml" />
    <ElementFile Location="CVs\FileDlg.htm" />
    <ElementFile Location="CVs\Repair.aspx" />
    <ElementFile Location="CVs\Schema.xml" />
    <ElementFile Location="CVs\Upload.aspx" />
    <ElementManifest Location="Notes\Elements.xml" />
    <ElementFile Location="Notes\Schema.xml" />
    <ElementManifest Location="Activites\Elements.xml" />
    <ElementFile Location="Activites\Schema.xml" />
    <ElementManifest Location="Demandes RDV\Elements.xml" />
    <ElementFile Location="Demandes RDV\Schema.xml" />
    <ElementManifest Location="Entretiens\Elements.xml" />
    <ElementFile Location="Entretiens\Schema.xml" />
    <ElementManifest Location="Formations\Elements.xml" />
    <ElementFile Location="Formations\Schema.xml" />
    <ElementManifest Location="Idees\Elements.xml" />
    <ElementFile Location="Idees\Schema.xml" />
    <ElementManifest Location="Mensualites\Elements.xml" />
    <ElementFile Location="Mensualites\Schema.xml" />   </ElementManifests> </Feature>`

and the manifest of the list instances feature:

`<Feature xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/" Title="Model ListInstances" Id="d61d526e-0e16-4bd4-87e1-1479d405e230" Scope="Web">   <ActivationDependencies>
    <ActivationDependency FeatureId="ab765f54-0a2b-4aa9-b87c-f5066849dc4a" FeatureTitle="Model ListDefinitions" />   </ActivationDependencies>   <ElementManifests>
    <ElementManifest Location="FormationsInstance\Elements.xml" />
    <ElementManifest Location="EntretiensInstance\Elements.xml" />
    <ElementManifest Location="Demandes RDV Instance\Elements.xml" />
    <ElementManifest Location="CVsInstance\Elements.xml" />
    <ElementManifest Location="ActivitesInstance\Elements.xml" />
    <ElementManifest Location="MensualitesInstance\Elements.xml" />
    <ElementManifest Location="NotesInstance\Elements.xml" />
    <ElementManifest Location="IdeesInstance\Elements.xml" />   </ElementManifests> </Feature>`

Can anyone help me please ?

Comment: maybe you can try disabling automatic activation of the features, and then do it manually from the UI and check for errors and logs. without seeing the code, that's what I can advise

Comment: thanks for your reply.In fact I disabled the activation of the features while deploying my solution and I activated them from the Sharepoint Site , the activation is successfully achieved for the first two features which are Feature_ContentTypes_Fields and Feature_ListDefinitions , but it didn't work with Feature_ListInstances.( Sorry, something went wrong
Cannot complete this action.

Please try again.).Any suggestion ?

Comment: enable debbugging (web.config), check ULS logs

Comment: @RihabBENCHHIBA when you get the "Sorry, something went wrong Cannot complete this action" there should be also a correlation id. Using that correlation id you can get to the actual error logged in the SharePoint uls system. Also, it would provide useful if you could post the "code" for the third feature.

Comment: In fact the third feature, as I mentioned before, contains list istances of my solution custom lists .

Comment: @RihabBENCHHIBA ok, but how are the instances created? Caml/Declarative only approach or you have some code running? We need to see the actual declaration/code and possibly the error message from the log files.

Comment: just caml/declarative approach , there is no code running

Comment: (Guid databaseId, SqlSession session, SPFileStreamManager spfstm, Object[] metadataRow, SPRowset contentRowset, SPDocumentBindRequest& dbreq, SPDocumentBindResults& dbres)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPSqlClient.GetDocumentContentRow(Int32 rowOrd, Object ospFileStmMgr, SPDocumentBindRequest& dbreq, SPDocumentBindResults& dbres... e10eaa9c-3d26-c0a1-b778-12d8ab6a7b4e

Comment: you can use usl viewer (http://sharepointlogviewer.codeplex.com/) to visualize the uls log properly. then, I recommend you remove your comments and update your question with relevant log entries

Comment: seems you are getting an exception in Model_Feature_ListInstances on http://app:1111/Lists/Formations. make sure both the url and the list names are right. consider deleting the list in case the feature is trying to create it and it is already there

Comment: the problem is with all list instances , i'm sure that the url as well as list names are right .

Comment: I created another project that contains custom columns ( surname , name , address) , content type named person and a custom list named PersonList. I put the columns and the content type in a feature , the list Def in another feature and the list instance in a third feature . while deploying , i have the same problem so i'm sure that there is a problem in the creation of any list instance .

Comment: there is a suspicious filenotfound. maybe you can run in debug mode and try to find out. once you activate the feature manually it should stop on your activation breakpoints

Comment: and do post your list definition and list instance manifests. maybe we can find problematic references in there

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your list instance must have a FeatureId attribute that maches your ListDefinition's feature.

This is not added by default, so it's likelly that this is why you are getting "Cannot complete this action".

E.g.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Elements xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/">
  <ListInstance Title="ListDef"
                OnQuickLaunch="TRUE"
                TemplateType="10000"
                Url="Lists/ListDef"
                Description="My List Instance" FeatureId="ab765f54-0a2b-4aa9-b87c-f5066849dc4a">
  </ListInstance>
</Elements>
```

Comment: Always the same error is displayed.

Comment: you can try setting both features to the same scope, but I have just tested this locally and as long as the list instance contains the FeatureId of the Feature where the list definition belongs to, it should work

Comment: similar post: http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/39839/error-activate-feature-list-template-instance-in-site-definition

Comment: when I try to activate the list instance from my site , an error page is displayed : Runtime Error 
In order to enable the details of this specific error message to be viewable on the local server machine, the "mode" attribute of <customErrors> tag within  "web.config" configuration file must be "RemoteOnly"
 
but when I try to overwrite the web.config file , I can't save it (save failed : please check if this file is opened in another program) or it is not the case.

Comment: you can stop iis, make a backup of webconfig, and change it. also, close your visual studio. it may be locking down the file as well

Comment: or open the Editor on administrator mode .